# Computing the symbols of a composition of operators.

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

[image]

Hello. I am studying the compositions of operators in the book "Pseudo differential operators" by Helmut Abel. I understood the calculations in the image, but, when considering the following example, with $P_1 u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)\widehat{u}(\xi))$ and $P_2 u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)$ with symbols $p_1(\xi)=1+|\xi|^2$ and $p_2(\xi)=\frac{1}{1+|\xi|^2)}$, I can't get that $\int \int \mathrm{e}^{-ix'\cdot \xi'}p_1(\xi+\xi')p_2(\xi)dx'd\xi'=1$ (I don't know if this is true either, but I suppose it is so that the composition of the two operators coincides with the identity)

Question: $\int\int\mathrm{e}^{ix'\cdot \xi'}(1+|\xi+\xi'|^2)\frac{1}{1+|\xi|^2}dx'd\xi'=1?$